# ConTeXt footnotes font

Tags: footnotes, context

I wanted to know if there was a way to specify the font to use for the footnote numbers (both those in the main text and the actual footnote text).

For example, supposing that the mainfont is EB Garamond:

```
\starttext
    Main text[number in Comic Sans]\foonote{[number in Comic Sans] footnote text}
 \stoptext
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `\setupfootnotedefinition`:

```
\setupfootnotedefinition
   [headstyle=italic, 
    location=top, 
    color=red, 
    headcolor=blue]

\starttext
Lorem ipsum\footnote{dolor sic amet.}
\stoptext
```

Also you can check https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupfootnotes and https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupdescriptions for more control (in ConTeXt footnotes are description objects)

Comment: Excuse me but how would your answer be able to change the font of the number of the footnotes?  With all due respect, you missed the point.  The question is not to change the style, for example,  monospace style, but to change the font.  So I imagined an answer like: associate a command such as definefontfamily or something similar to the style of the footnotes. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Zezzo: You can use `headstyle={\switchtobodyfont[Comic Sans Setup]}` . You can switch both the  font and the font style using the `style` key.

Comment: I Will try! Thank you